# How to get the return of a async function called by an event in html?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm developing an Angular app, it has a button with a click event.
But the method is async using subscribe.
I need to get the return to call another method in another class.

I need to call **player.start()** after **listItems.getData()** is finished, the problem is that **getData()** is called in the html and I need to catch the termination event for this method in order to trigger the **start()** method.

player.html:

```html
<button color="primary" (click)="listItems.getData()" ...
```

ListItems.ts:

```js
export class ListItems {
    ...
    getData() {
        /**
        ** I call getData() in Html context, making it impossible to 
        ** get the result inside a class in typescript
        **/
        ...
        return this.http.get(url).subscribe(res => {
            this.data = res;
        }
    }
}
```

player.ts:

```js
export class Player {
    constructor(public listItems: ListItems) {
    }
    start() {
        /**
        ** start method only can be called after listItems.data get data
        **/
        let alldata = this.listItems.data.replace('\n', '');
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ListItems can emit an event (e.g. onData) to its parent component when the http request is complete. Then the Player component can bind the “start()” method call to the ListItem component’s “onData” event.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "list-items",
  template: `
    <h2>Items:</h2>
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of data">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
    <button (click)="getData()">Get Data</button>
  `,
})
export class ListItems {

  @Output()
  dataReceived = new EventEmitter<void>();

  data: string[] = [];

  getData() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // simulate http request
      this.data = ["hello", "world"];
      this.dataReceived.emit();
    }, 2000);
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <h1>Player</h1>
    <list-items (dataReceived)="start()"></list-items>
    <h2>start() invoked: {{ invoked }} </h2>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class Player {
  title = "CodeSandbox";

  invoked: boolean = false;

  start() {
    this.invoked = true;
  }
}
```

See working toy example: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-angular?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark